# Stop Full Screen Web App caching on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, caching

I have a web app and in order to make it full screen when I save the link to the home screen I've added the following meta data:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

This works fine, removes the address bar and the web app still functions as it should.

However, when I lock the iPad, then unlock it and return to the web app, the callbacks for ajax functions and any DOM manipulations, such as jQuery's slideToggle(), fail to work.

I've spent a lot of time trying to research the issue and I believe the issue occurs because of caching because it works fine without the meta tag.

I've tried adding a timestamp to the end of js/css files (e.g. stylesheet.css?v=TIMESTAMP) to see if it would stop the caching, but I've had no luck.

Is there any way I can stop it from caching?

Comment: Not certain whether the problem is because of caching, but if you want to be explicit about what should and shouldn't be cached, you could define a cache manifest and list certain files under "network" so they are never cached.

Comment: Just tried adding a cache manifest file, but that's not worked :(

Comment: @Karl - Any luck? I'm facing the same issue :(

Comment: @imguru Unfortunately not, I had to abandon using it as I was unable to find anything which fixed the issue.

Comment: Same here, but I unfortunately cannot abandon it :(